# How can I add equivalent space with the menu shown in this HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was cleaning up my code before it became more complex and noticed this. I used transparent box's as spacers, but that method is obsolete. So I was wondering if there was a more traditional way. I've researched methods online, but none of them are compatible with my markup.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />



    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/your/jquery/script.js"></script>
    <script src="dropit.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropit.css" type="text/css" />




    <style> 
    body
    {
    background:url("");
    background-size:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-top:40px;
    }
    <!--
     a:hover{color:#c0c0c0;}
    -->
        .navLink {
        color: #000000;    
        text-decoration: none !important;}
    ul
    {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-size: SMALL;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: regular;}

    li
    {
    display:inline;
    }
    </style>


    </head>
    <body>



    <img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="100" height="70">
    <HR COLOR="#C0C0C0" WIDTH="100%">

    <ul id="nav" >

    <img border="0" src="http://www.miacreative.com/ESW/Images/WHITE-BOX-MID.png" alt="Vealed" width="450" height="1"> <li><a href="#">
        <li><a href="#" class="navLink">MEN'S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navLink">WOMEN'S</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navLink">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
        <li><a href="#" class="navLink">BLOG</a>
        <li><a href="#" class="navLink">SALE</a>
    </ul>


    <HR COLOR="#C0C0C0" WIDTH="100%">

    <ul id="nav" >
    <img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="0" height="2">

    <p><p align="center"><img border="0" src="http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/6192/5eo7.png" alt="Vealed" width="800" height="500">


    <img border="0" src="http://az61389.vo.msecnd.net/6/_ui/img/mosaic/big-transparent-block.png" alt="Vealed" width="70" height="2">

    </ul>










    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.menu').dropit();
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's "equivalent space"? Use CSS to fix spacing issues. Study [this](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/) for instance.

Comment: Please explain how javascript and jquery relate to the problem, or remove the tags.

Comment: I was using javascript to create the dropdown menu

Comment: You need to fix your markup before you start thinking about styling it.  Inline-styles are obsolete (at least the way you're using them), your paragraph tags are both nested AND unclosed, and your list doesn't have any list-items!  At this point spacing is the least of your worries.